# I am receiveing Non HTTP response message: Illegal character in path at index 20 in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

In HTTP Request details I have added the URL of the website

I want to target to a not existing URL if that is possible so that we can check something.
It will be ideal when we can target a random_number
Now I added a regular expression.

But I receive this error:
Response code:Non HTTP response code: java.net.URISyntaxException
Response message:Non HTTP response message: Illegal character in path at index 20: https://***/${randomNumber}

HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType:
DataEncoding: null

[image]

[image]

I am a complete newbie with this. Hope that someone can help.

Comment: Still nog solved the problem.  Still the same issue :( 

What can cause this problem?

Answer (score 0):

> **Template**
>
> The template used to create a string from the matches found. This is an arbitrary string with special elements to refer to groups within the regular expression. The syntax to refer to a group is: `$1$` to refer to group **1**, `$2$` to refer to group **2**, etc. `$0$` refers to whatever the entire expression matches.

So you need to change "Template" to `$1$`

More information:

- [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)
- [Apache JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I changed it but still the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it on another way :) See here my solution.

[image]

Comment: Screenshots aren't very accessible. Please also describe what you did.